# Sybase search query

Tags: sql, sybase

I am working on a Sybase stored procedure that is taking 4 nullable input parameters, and fetches data from a table.

```
@name varchar(20) = null
@city varchar(20) = null
@deparment varchar(30) = null
@depCode varchar(10) = null
```

**Query**

```
select * from company
where
(UPPER(name) like UPPER('%' @name '%') OR @name is NULL) AND
(UPPER(city) like UPPER('%' @city '%') OR @city is NULL) AND
UPPER(deparment) LIKE
CASE WHEN @deparment IS NOT NULL AND @depCode is NOT NULL
THEN UPPER('%' @deparment '%') END AND
UPPER(depCode) LIKE
CASE WHEN @deparment IS NOT NULL AND @depCode is NOT NULL
THEN UPPER('%' @depCode '%') END
```

CASE statement is not working properly. if I comment on both case statements and pass input value or not for name and city query is working fine. @deparment & @depCode are dependent on each other.

My Requirement -

- if I pass null for @deparment and valid input for @depCode it should
  ignore the condition and fetch data on behalf of @name and @city
- if I pass null for @depCode  and valid input for @deparment it
  should ignore the condition and fetch data on behalf of @name and
  @city
- if I pass valid input for @depCode and @deparment it fetches data on behalf of all 4 input.
- if I will not pass any input it should also fetch data.

Comment: Sybase is not SQL Server and they use different sql dialects (confusingly both named TSql but that is a historical anomaly). Tag removed.

Comment: please expand on what you mean by `CASE statement is not working properly`? your query relies on all 4x `where` clauses evaluating at 'true' in order for anything to be returned; while you could rewrite the query as a `union` of several separate queries (addressing each `@deparment / @depCode` combo), it may be easier to add an `ELSE` clause to each of the `CASE` statements ... with the objective being to ensure the associated `where` clauses always evaluate as `true` **and** provide the expected results ,,,

Comment: ... eg, if the current `CASE` test is false then what should `UPPER(deparmen)` be compared to (`LIKE`) in order to return a `true` but also not filter out any `deparment` values? `UPPER(deparment) LIKE CASE ... ELSE UPPER(deparment) END` ???  keep in mind these types of queries will likely require a full table scan so performance won't be the best